# How can I delete an image while it is open in listview?

Tags: c#, file-io, delete-file

I am trying to athis listview that shows images in a folder

```
public void LoadData()
{
    var imgList = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.jpg", 
    SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    myListView.ItemsSource = imgList;
}
```

The ListView ItemTemplate is an Image and a button to delete the Image
The click event of the button is handled as follows

```
private void DeleteImg(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string delImg = (string)(sender as Button).DataContext;
    File.Delete(delImg);
    LoadData();
}
```

I get the following error when I try to delete an image

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'xyz' because it is being used by another process.'

xyz is the file name obviously

I think it's because the image is open in ListView
Any ideas about how I can close the file before deleting it

What I have tried:

I tried

```
myListView.ItemsSource = null;
myListView.Items.Clear();
before delete
also:
System.GC.Collect();
System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comment: reset `image.ImageSource`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this and it works;

```
public void LoadData()
{
var imgList = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
myListView.ItemsSource = imgList;
foreach (string f in imgList)
            {

                var bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.BeginInit();
                bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bi.UriSource = new Uri(f);
                imgLister.Add(bi);
                bi.EndInit();
                bi.Freeze();
            }
}
```

Freeze() methode Frees up memory, and allows file to be deleted